# PHP - Is possible to find if user is browsing from beind a Router and get Router Info

Tags: php, networking, router

**Hello guys.**

***I think it isn't possible just using PHP, but just to be sure.***

- Is it possible for PHP to know if the
  user is accessing the web from behind
  a [Router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router)?
- And if yes, how can i get some
  information about that router, like:

  - Router Name, Brand, Serial Number, ...
  - Users connected in the same network.
- Can PHP also find the Local IP
  Address for the visitor in that
  Network?

A few simple questions. To which i haven't found a solid answer, and i tough that some PHP genius could tell me. And teach me.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT: Motives for this privacy invasive question**

I didn't thought that i had to say this... But i guess i do

I was writing a couple functions that would get the browser preferred languages and finding out from which Country the user comes based on the IP, to deliver my website content in the right language to the visitor.

Then i started to think, most people browse from behind the router, can i find out if they are indeed?

---

Then it just came to my mind to do one of those simple programs that display network details, people connected on your network. My idea was to do that, but Web App Based not Desktop App Based as all other programs of this kind.

I appreciate privacy above everything as most developers do, so i kind of understand the Down Votes, i would probably Down Vote myself.

I'm sorry if you misjudge me due to my weird question, i have nothing to do so.. These things just popped up on my head.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: not possible.

Comment: I don't think people should be voting this question down just because they don't like the implications of what he's asking. It's a perfectly valid technical question.

Comment: @Chad Birch: Again I have to agree. Especially if one want to learn how to make a system secure or whatever, one has to know what attacks are possible and which information is available in order to deal with it.

Comment: If you want to use it for language detection maybe you can find something about how Google solved this issue. And if they don't care about routers I don't think you have to ;)

Comment: @Felix: I don't like the way Google handles Language detection. They start by the language of the country where you are based on your IP (now think of your self as in constant travel), not your Browser Preferred Languages. I start by going to the preferred languages of your browser. usually they are 3, ordered by a factor from 1 to 0.5 being 1 your preferred language.

Comment: @Fábio Antunes: I didn't mean how Google handles the detection completely. I also hate that set the language based on the IP first. But still, the might have a good solution for *that*. (of course you should still go with browser settings first!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, are you talking about finding out information about users visiting your website? Keep in mind that this implies an intrusion into their privacy (you can try it with yourself though ;))

> Is it possible for PHP to know if the user is accessing the web from behind a Router?

No you cannot. Only when you know that e.g. you have a lot visitors from one company and they all have the same IP address, they might be behind a router but it could also be a proxy.

> And if yes, how can i get some information about that router, like:
>
> - Router Name, Brand, Serial Number, ...

If you have the IP you might be able to discover various things about a host with tools such as  [nmap](http://nmap.org/). You might be able to find out the brand of a router and host system but definitely not serial number and such stuff. nmap is not PHP though.
**Note:** The use of such tools without permission to do so is illegal in some countries. In any way, the use of such tools without permission is morally questionable .

> - Users connected in the same network.

As I mentioned in the first question, if you have *different* users with the *same* IP address they *might* be in the same network. They could also be in different sub-networks. Anyway you cannot get their local IP addresses.

> Can PHP also find the Local IP Address for the visitor in that Network?

See previous answer.

---

You see, everything is very vague and mostly based on assumptions. You cannot get reliable information and I am very glad that we are not totally transparent yet.

Once we all use `IPv6`, the whole story is a different one.

Comment: By comparing User-Agent headers from multiple sessions originating at the same IP, you can probably detect the presence of many routers (if the same IP reports a Mac browser and another on Windows Vista, there's probably NAT involved).

Comment: Proxy can be differentiated from NAT based on the TTL behavior (as compared to e.g. pinging the same address).  But determining that is beyond the capabilities of PHP I suspect (of course it depends on the web server and any additional functions it provides to get low-level packet information).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Ok I have to confess I have not thought about that in such a detail. But I'm always happy to learn something new as I'm also interested in network security. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Sorry for my ignorance about the subject, but you sound to have many knowledge about networks. Can you share a bit more what you know, specially about TTL (don't know what it is) behavior. Thanks :D

Comment: TTL is designed to fight infinite routing loops.  It's a number inside the IP header (so it exists in TCP, UDP, ICMP packets among others).  Every router that forwards a packet must reduce the TTL (usually by one, but subtracting more is permitted).  When the TTL reaches zero, the packet is thrown away.  It's used for traceroute, since in many cases the router throwing away the packet will send a message back to the sender.  Now, a NAT is a kind of router, it replaces the source and/or destination address and port numbers, but the TTL comes from the original sender.

Comment: (continued) A proxy maintains separate connections to client and server, so when it sends out a request it's a packet created by the proxy with a fresh new TTL determined by the proxy independent of the client.  Of course you could confuse the difference by configuring a NAT to use a fairly low TTL for outgoing packets (i.e. ICMP reply) and clamp NAT-ed packets to the same TTL, my proposed test would then incorrectly call it a proxy.

Comment: (continues) A proxy could also pretend to be a NAT using per-connection TTL settings.  Just setting the proxy software's TTL lower than ping replies would be sufficient to fool my proposed test.  But in the end, proxies and NATs are both routers, just at different levels (in OSI model, NAT is Layer 3-4 router and proxy is Layer 7).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: No worries I forgot that you mentioned to ping the IP address and compare the TTL behavior. Thank you.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Considering that routers repeat the same packet, though increasing connection stability and network traffic. Any attempt to track they're TTL would be overwhelming, i think.
A packet every time he goes through a router, isp, ... He takes a tag from everyplace he as gone through right?

Comment: @Fabio: No, the TTL is stored inside the packet.  The router decreases the TTL on its way through.  Deciding whether to forward or discard the packet is a very simple check, whether the TTL is still positive or not.  So no it's not an overwhelming burden on the router.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: But isn't supposed the packet be protected and only able to be read by its end user? Thats what i remember from basic Network lessons back at school. Unless that they are wrong of course. So how would the router read the TTL and then decrease/increase it to send it again.

Comment: @Fabio: The only "protection" is that the packet is supposed to take the shortest path to its destination, which minimizes the number of people who can meddle with it.  And the routers are responsible for ensuring that.  Some protocols may add a signature to protect (by detecting changes) the payload, but they'll _always_ exclude the IP header simply because it _will_ change.  Any attempt to guard the IP header against modification will simply cause incompatibility with something like 99% of all networks (in fact any network with a router) because decreasing the TTL is mandated by the IP spec.

Comment: My guess. School sucks. I should trade school time for SO time.
@Ben Voigt: Thanks Ben for your time and patience i will look into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but it worries me a little.

So I'm glad that (as you suspected) it's not possible.

All the details you're asking about is information that there's no reason for anyone outside the local network to need, it would be a huge security problem if a router was broadcasting this to the world.

Comment: +1 for *but it worries me a little*... This was my first thought too.

Comment: But if you are behind a router and type your router IP in your Smartphone browser you end up on your Router Admin Panel.

Comment: @Fábio Antunes: So? What is your point? This is the internal IP of the router and the admin panel will (hopefully) only be accessible from the local network.

Comment: @Felix: Hopefully you said, and you're right, hopefully. Most Router admin panels are accessible from the Internet just by tipping your Internet IP into your browser. And now consider that most of its owners don't even change the manufacturer security settings. In this moment you could access: http://85.242.9.184 and change my wlan router settings if i haven't changed the security setting.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, by the design of the network protocols.
However, some routers uses special builds of PHP in its admin control panels.